# Show public events from Facebook in a map

Tags: facebook

I'm implementing a webpage using the Facebook tools and PHP SDK.
I've created the Facebook login/logout. I also have the coordinates (latitude and longitude) of the user accessing the webpage/app. But then, I want is to show in a map all the public Facebook events near the user during today.
So, what I need is the code lines that, using the coordinates, get the near events. Where do I have to write this lines? I imagine that into the index.php creating an "if" condition (if user is logged, get the events and show them in the map).

And what if I want to show all the public events related to a fixed keyword? For example: plot in a map the events near the user that are related to the word "music".

Thanks a lot!

Comment: it'd be better if you get into more programming first. you can use graph api (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/) and fql (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event) to pull the events, but the searching functionality based on location is currently unavailable, so you may think of something else or a clever workaround.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Actually, I've been learning about the Graph API and FQL. The problem is that I can't put all the pieces together to implement the complete request into my php file...
And then, how can I show the near events in a map? Is it impossible? Is there any other option? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome. actually there are many references on facebook.. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/ is for example, a complete example for uploading a photo (not the task you want, but has many parts in common). there are many php tutorials throughout the site. if you run by some code that you don't understand there, you are of course welcome to ask about the part you haven't understood.

Comment: Great. I found some code for what I want:
http://www.emoticode.net/php/google-maps-with-facebook-events.html
But the problem is that this code uses a "page_id" (apart from a app_id and an app_secret) to get the events, so it gets the events from a fanpage, instead of all the events "in the world". What changes should I try?

Comment: there starts the problem. you just can't query "all the events" on the world other than constrainting them with one of the indexable fields. according to the FQL reference at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event, only event id, creator id, and event name are indexable. you can only filter the events by those fields, if it helps. one possible option *may* be to make the user login with facebook, get their location, get the events that his/her friends are attending, and order them by their distance to the user.

Comment: Thanks can poyrazoğlu! So, can I use the event name? That would be great if I could show the events with the word "concert" (for example) in the name of the event...

Comment: well, the event name indexable, but we apparently can't search for some string inside a column. if you know the exact name of the event, then it can be used in WHERE constraint, but otherwise, you are limited to having at least another constraint on an indexable column. FQL doesn't support the SQL "LIKE" keyword, there is "strpos" function, but you can't use indexing with its output.

Comment: Great, thanks @canpoyrazoğlu! I'm nearly there. I've been able to show in a map all the events from a fanpage. Now, what I want is to show all the events from all the fanpages I like. I know that I can show all the ids from the fanpages I like doing this:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?fields=id
But I want to get the events from all these "id"s (not only from one id. Any ideas, pleas? :D

Comment: it's impractical to do it with graph requests one by one as you've possibly imagined, so you'd need to use FQL for that. getting all the events from all the pages that the user has liked would take some time though. the fql is `select eid, name from event where creator in (SELECT page_id from page WHERE page_id in (SELECT page_id from page_fan where uid = me()) LIMIT 100)`. i've limited it to 100 pages that the user likes, otherwise it takes too much time and the request fails. hope that it helps though.

Comment: Thanks, @canpoyrazoğlu! :)
But then, how can I put the events on markers?
Because withe the previous implementation, I did this:

$sMarker = '';
$i=0;
foreach($oEvents->data as $oEvent)
if(property_exists($oEvent->venue, 'latitude'))
 $sMarker .= sprintf("aMarker[%d] = new Array(%f, %f, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')\n", $i++, $oEvent->venue->latitude, $oEvent->venue->longitude, $oEvent->name, $oEvent->description, $oEvent->location, $oEvent->start_time);

Comment: well, I can't really tell the exact code, I'm not a PHP guy so if I tried to write it here I'd make mistakes. but you can go to Graph API Explorer on Facebook developer site and go to FQL tab, then type and execute the FQL. check the results, then according to the data structure return, change your PHP code to parse that data.